# Jimdo javascript doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to add a javascript widget on my Jimdo website
The javascript works perfectly on other CMS but not on Jimdo.
Does anybody wonder why ? French customer support doesn't seem to understand my question...
If you had a similar experience, can you help me ?
Thank you !

The code looks like this :

```html
<script src="https://www.onair-alert.com/bundles/oawidget/widgets/01/script.js" type="text/javascript">
{
    "user": 1833,
    "logo": 1,
    "widget_title": "1",
    "count": false,
    "type": 1,
    "message": true,
    "style": {
        "width": "350px"
    },
    "widget-id": "nyfneh4paf1e9gyw40bob",
    "alerts-enabled": true,
    "alerts-type": "latest",
    "font-color": "232323",
    "bg-color": "ffffff",
    "border-color": "cdcdcd",
    "bg-opacity": 90,
    "attr": {},
    "url": "https://www.onair-alert.com/henri-guaino"
}
</script>
<noscript><a href="https://www.onair-alert.com/henri-guaino">Henri Guaino sur OnAir</a></noscript>
```

Comment: What is the expected result? What is the actual result? I. e. what do you mean by “script works perfectly” and “script does not work”?

Comment: The expected result is a window like the one you can find for instance on this website : http://www.brigittekuster.fr/ , below the title "Suivez-moi sur OnAir". The actual result is an error message.